# Windows 10 Install Hanging on Internet Connection

Tags: wifi, windows, install, internet

I am doing a clean install on my 15" MacBook Pro, i7, via Boot Camp 6.1.0, Mojave 10.14.5.  I downloaded the latest version of Windows 10 via Microsoft (as of July 2019).  All installs fine and when it reboots into Windows 10 to finish the installation process, it hangs on the screen with blue box that says "Let's Connect you to a Network", but there is no option to choose a network.

Although I entered my wifi and passcode prior to this step during the install process, it does not see an internet connection in which to choose.  I've tried starting over clean three times and it stalls on the same place each time.

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can resolve this?  Sorry if this issue has been posted before, I searched and searched and could not find it.

Comment: I believe that the wireless drivers are installed as part of Bootcamp, which occurs after you've installed Windows, and booted into Windows itself

Comment: If so, they must not be working.  May try hardwiring ethernet via USB-C adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue.  Can’t explain it, but deleted downloaded ISO File, increased sector size to 128GB.  Windows installed and loaded as before, but got stuck at exactly same spot on not connecting to the internet (blue box on screen in Windows 10 start up).  However, the lower left hand corner now changed it’s radio button to bypass the internet connection.  Windows then finished install, loaded and started up.

BUT!.....No wifi!!! (another issue I’ve seen on this forum).  Here’s how you resolve that:

1. Insert formatted USB Drive.
   Open Boot Camp Assistant from Utilities.
2. At top pull down Action and select Download Windows Support Software.
3. When USB install is completed, Re-boot to Windows while leaving USB inserted.
4. In Windows, go to USB Drive, Boot Camp folder, and start Setup.
5. Drivers will get installed and Wifi should work (mine did).

What a frustrating 2 days this has been!

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

As a complete novice to anything related to computers I just clicked on “I have no internet connection” and then “continue with limited setup”. It continued to install and my desktop screen eventually appeared.

Once on the desktop screen I was able to select my internet connection and Windows then automatically continued with finishing the setup with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Dr google does not report any issue with the Windows 10 installer requiring an internet connection or any issue with the MacBook Pro and Windows 10 installer.

Did you use the BootCamp installer to create the thumb drive?  I'll bet there is an $OEM$ folder in the root that adds drivers to the Windows installation process.

See https://support.apple.com/en-lamr/HT201468 for instructions.

Comment: Bootcamp did not require me to do a USB bootable drive.  The Windows partition was created and it boots up in Windows but does not connect to internet to finish.  I will look at Bootcamp again more closely and see if I had missed that (but I don't think so).

Comment: That's the part that's missing.  The $OEM$ folder contains drivers that the windows installer will need to install windows.  This contains USB-C drivers and wifi drivers as well as others...

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  If they are missing, how and where do I put them back?  Or should I just try to re-download Windows ISO file and start over?

Comment: You'll have to go back to the ISO and start over.  When it creates the bootable partition check for the $OEM$ folder at the root of the drive.  That's what is going to have your drivers that Windows will need for the install.